Film about group of girls stalking their male neighbour
Okay, so there are girls in an apartment, spying a male neighbour on a different building (Like right next to it). They're looking through a window to see this guy.
The scenes I remembered:
So the this girl (the main character) spying at the guy, then her friend wakes up then shows her thumb, which is red because she sucked it hard. lmao.
The girls went inside the guys apartment to take a closer look, then the guy came in and the girls hid in the bathroom where the guy took a dump. successfully the girls went back undetected.
The main character visits the guy, they sat on a couch, then the guy threw a knife on the wall which killed a Fly.
Then the girls think that the guy is a Serial Killer or a Spy, police, or something.
That's all that I remembered. I think its between 2000-2010 and American English film.

Could be any inspired movie from Rear Window. Any idea on the year release? Language ? Not a TV Show ?

You're looking for Head Over Heels starring  Monica Potter and Freddie Prinze Jr.
It has everything you described.

Amanda Pierce is from Iowa and works as a restorer of Renaissance paintings for the New York Metropolitan Museum. She has just finished another frustrating relationship, when she found her boy-friend with a model on her bed. She decides to move and share a flat with four stupid but nice super-models. She meets Jim Winston, who lives in front of her window. She falls in love with him. One day, she sees Jim killing a woman - Megan O'Brien - through her window and Amanda and her four roommates decide to investigate what really happened.




Here's the bathroom scene



